# Conditional Style on SharePoint List View

Tags: view, sharepoint-2010, formatting

I got a standard webpart that displays the contents of a document library.

If one Field has a specific value I want to  Display the Contents Bold and in a different Color.

I can achieve that by going to the document library list and modify the view by using SharePoint designer and adding "Conditional Formatting" and "Format Row".

The results look great in Designer. (Red and Bold)

In the List View the Color is lost, but Bold is still visible.

On the Website using the WebPart for Display all formatting is lost.

What can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by not modifying the VIEW in SharePoint Designer, but the PAGE. Weird stuff... :)